# window.open() Opens wrong URL. Browser remembers it until logout

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

When I use below code to open a new window for creating new person it works only once:

```
<a class="special" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.myurl.blahblah/index_details.php?id=null&amp;page=1', 'personDetails', 'left=50, top=20, width=850, height=440, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, statusbar=no');">New worker</a>
```

this index_details.php is used to show some person details data depending on his/her id, and when I pass null it creates new one and redirects using header function to  itself with new id. Code looks ok but I paste it below:

```
<?php
require_once('start_session.php');
require_once('constant.data.php');
//**********************************************************************************//
$main = array();
$main_phrases = array(
                    'error' => iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', 'Error occur!')
                    );

$db = new DB();
//**********************************************************************************//

if ($_GET['id'] == "null")
    {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO main_information (last_name, first_name, lastmod, lastentry) VALUES ("NEW","WORKER", CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE);';
    $result = $db->dbQuery($sql);
    $sql = 'SELECT MAX(id) AS lastId FROM main_information where last_name="NEW" and first_name="WORKER";';
    $result = $db->dbQuery($sql);
    $row = $db->dbFetchArray($result);
    $li = $row['lastId'];
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO additional_information (id_person, blacklist, medical_cert, application_ready, supervisor) VALUES ('.$li.',"N", "N", "N", "N");';
    $result = $db->dbQuery($sql);
    header('Location: ' . _MAIN_DOMAIN_ . 'index_details.php?id=' . $li . '&page=1');
    }
//**********************************************************************************//
if (isset($_FILES['face_photo']) && $_FILES['face_photo']['name'] != '' && $_GET['id'] != 'null' && $_GET['id'] != '')
    {
    $ext = substr($_FILES['face_photo']['name'], -4, 4);
    $fileName = 'photo' . $_GET['id'] . $ext;
    $uploadfile = SERVER_DIR . 'photo/' . $fileName;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['face_photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
        $sql = 'UPDATE additional_information SET photo = "'.$fileName.'" WHERE id_person = '.intval($_GET['id']).';';
        if ($db->dbQuery($sql))
            header('Location: ' . _MAIN_DOMAIN_ . 'index_details.php?id=' . $_GET['id'] . '&page=1');
        }
    else    die('Uploaded file is incorrect!');
    }
//**********************************************************************************//
$smarty     = new Smarty;
$smarty->assign('main', $main);
$smarty->template_dir = SERVER_DIR.'tpl/';
$smarty->compile_dir = SERVER_DIR.'templates_c';
$smarty->cache_dir = SERVER_DIR.'cache';
$smarty->display('default_details.tpl');
```

?>

My problem is that anchor from first snippet works only once. When I close personDetails window and want to create new person it opens the previously created one not the new one.
Issue occurs in ie,chrome,FF until I clear browser data (what log outs me).

Even when I manually enter _http://www.mydomain.com.pl/admin/index_details.php?id=null&page=1
it redirects me for example to
_http://www.mydomain.com.pl/admin/index_details.php?id=1666&page=1 not to 
_http://www.mydomain.com.pl/admin/index_details.php?id=1667&page=1
(assuming that I've just created user 1666).

This is CMS written by some one else which I have to fix. I guess it might be something stored within session, cache, cookies,... Any tools/clues how to find it and fix it? I'm not a web dev every day.

My client claims that it worked fine some time ago, so maybe something shanged in PHP or javascript or all browsers recently?

Comment: is ok if you post the codes coming from index_details.php here? there might be some condition there that tells the program to redirect to previously created id when the page was already visited with the null value and that is what we should be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found answer to my question.
Adding to index_details.php this code:

```
header( "Expires: Mon, 20 Dec 1998 01:00:00 GMT" );
header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT" );
header( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header( "Pragma: no-cache" );
```

helped.

First I thought it is not the case as I saw those headers in some html meta tags included to the pages. Asking PHP to send those few more headers before header('Location: ...') makes the browser forgot the redirection.